# Is it possible to enable execution of files from a cifs mount in bash?

Tags: filesystems, permissions

I have a remote mount with cifs and it would seem there is no way to have bash execute scripts from that mount, is it possible to enable such execution?

```
ls -lh ini*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alan 500 222 2012-03-23 10:16 initall.sh

bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

./initall.sh
bash: ./initall.sh: Permission denied
```

The cifs mount seems to support also unix extensions as I am able to chmod the file correctly.

Here follows the mount options:
    user,auto,pass=`***`,uid=alan,user=`***`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `user` mount option turns off `exec` by default. Change the mount options to include `exec` explicitly.

Comment: This only worked on the command line. If I put 'exec' in the options list of /etc/fstab, it doesn't work. Strange.

Comment: @MichaelR.Hines `exec` works the same in `fstab` and on the `mount` command line. If it didn't work for you, it's because of some specific circumstance (there's a different matching `fstab` entry, the filesystem was already mounted before, …)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Ubuntu is screwing something up. I very clearly added a new line to /etc/fstab followed by "mount -a", followed by examiniming the mtab and the mount command is definitely not respecting what I put into the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can always execute script with

```
sh ./your_script.sh
```

or

```
bash ./your_script.sh
```

or whatever shell you use.
It works even noexec mount option turned on.